# Angular: Unit testing GET method in service

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, methods, get

I have a service method that returns item and unit test for the get method. However, the coverage shows that the getter method is not covered. Can you suggest what am I doing wrong in unit test?

```
export class ItemService{
#item: Item;
  get item(): Item{
    return this.#item;
  }
}
```

```
import itemMock from '../mocks/item-response.json';
describe('ItemService', () => {
  let itemService: ItemService;
  it('should get item information', () => {
      itemService['#item'] = itemMock ;
      spyOnProperty(itemService, 'item').and.returnValue(itemMock);
      expect(itemService['#item']).toEqual(itemMock );
  });
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting `itemService['#item'] = itemMock ;` if you spy on the property afterwards? `expect(service.#item).toEqual(itemMock)` should do the trick

Comment: But then I am never assigning any data to #item so I have nothing to return, or isn´t that so? I removed ```itemService['#item'] = itemMock ;``` but this still does not solve the coverage

Comment: You do assign data with the returnValue. But the point of a Getter would be to have also a Setter, so you would not have to handle the property directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think the problem is your spy is actually replacing the getter, and this one is never called.
Maybe you could change strategy and only check on the private property without Spy ?

Comment: I modified the line ```spyOnProperty(itemService, 'item').and.returnValue(itemMock);``` to ```const spy = spyOnProperty(itemService, 'item').and.returnValue(itemMock);``` and then called ```expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();``` but I got error:  Expected spy to have been called.

Comment: Hi, I modified my answer, and I think you probably could avoid the Spy for such a code, because it does replace the getters and setters. And also, there is very little value in such a coverage, even if you do pass in these functions.

Comment: My pleasure, post any solution you come up with :)

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(itemService.item).toEqual(itemMock);
```